# Spring Sub State Machine doesn't initiate

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I have been developing a program containing a state machine. It has gotten overly complex now and I was waiting till the sub machine UML support was added. But even though I have followed the instructions in the 1.2.2 reference document, The sub machine won't initiate. The machine hangs at the state "Test" State. 
Please refer to the attached link to the uml file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9PT7E5L1ac9dmNRSUVfZ3JfcTA

Is there any way to start all submachines at the start of the application. Only the parent machine gets started

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot what uml statechart looks like?

Comment: At least you should remove `SmDiagram` and `AutomaticTopupSM` as we don't support multiple machines in same xml unless those are submachine references. Not sure if this is issue in this case.

Comment: Other than that I don't immediately see anything wrong. One of a most complex configs I've seen done in papyrus so maybe you've found a bug. Would you be able to craft a test case I could run as there's so much stuff related to your env that I can't run it as is.

Comment: Sm Diagram is a Sub-machine reference for "Test State". So When I feed the machine with TOP_ERR event, the state goes to TestState and Hangs. is there any additional configurations that I need to do for the submachine to initiate. because the other paths are working well, its just that the SmDiagram- which is a sub a machine reference,  that wont start and wait at its initial state as it is supposed to do.

Comment: I will send you my code and a test case in a while.

Comment: There's no special configs needed. It should go directly to its substate `test` as that's the initial state. You should also see `TestState` as parent to be active as well. There's `testSimpleSubmachineRef` in `UmlStateMachineModelFactoryTests` which is very similar. Try to do similar test to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm now re-reading your question and you said it hangs at `Test` state. I previously assumed it just hangs at parent `TestState` without going to its initial child state `test`. For `Test` not sure if you meant `test` or `TestState`.

It's little unclear that what actually happens and what states machine goes. But looking at this statechart, if it properly goes to `TestState` and then `test`, machine is in gridlock as there's no transitions which would take it out from there.

At minimum `TestState` should have outgoing transition to somewhere else.

Comment: that was a typo it should be hangs at "TestState". And I figured out the mistake, I have only updated the statemachine version and not uml to 1.2.2. My bad. It works well.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into it this deep. I have a few more questions about timeouts, will post another thread on it

Comment: Ok I got another doubt on exit points and I have posted a question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579538/spring-sub-state-machine-exit-point-to-parent-machine . I would be glad if you could assist me