# Spring sub state machine Exit point to parent machine

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have successfully implemented a state machine and also a sub machine with a reference from the initial. Now I'm stuck at a point where I cannot think about any way of linking an exit point to it. 
The links to my model is given.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9PT7E5L1ac9LTZlZWV5bWx1V1U

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9PT7E5L1ac9RnR6UUtrMkRoZE0

If you look at it, I have referenced a sub-machine from "DirectQuery" State (marked in red in the parent machine- img2).
Now I have a problem in linking the exit point to the parent. If there are two exit points, how can I handle both of them?

Comment: This is actually a very good question as I'm pretty sure uml spec is pretty vague about details as this. I need to go through spec if there's any ideas. We're also stepping in uml statemachine so if you can add tag `state-machines` as well. Could you also add this as a feature request to github repo as there's some users who know uml concepts better than I do. They may add some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, currently not supported but I realised it's actually defined in spec and papyrus also have it(though a bit hidden in properties editor). Created [gh-323](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/323) to implement this.

Comment: `1.2.x` snapshots should now have fix for this. Issue above contains more info how it was done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664368/spring-state-machinr-timeout-always-fires-when-using-connection-factory Please refer my next question

Comment: Hi can I know if i Can use pooling instead of a factory with UML?

Comment: afaik, uml doesn't have anything to do with it vs normal javaconfig. both can return statemachine and statemachinefactory.

Comment: How do I do that? configure it to use a pool? what is the targetBeanName then?

Comment: with UML? I couldn't find one that has UML AND a pool. Im not using a builder, so I don't have the bean public StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachineTarget().  so I can't figure out the target bean