# Spring State Machine timeout always execute when using connection factory

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

This time I have a question about timeouts on the state machine.
My scenario is like this, referring to the below image

[image: State machine <part>]

On entering StateBasic, I perform some action and the machine given by the Factory waits at WaitForTemplateResult till one of the events either VAS_QRY_RES or MAIN_QRY_RES.

Now theres also a timeout which fires after 30seconds.
So what happens now is the timeout is however fired even if VAS_QRY_RES or MAIN_QRY_RES comes.

I studied this problem and the explanation I was able to render is that when I first enter the StateBasic, the StateMachineFactory allocates a machine with a uuid, and when VAS_QRY_RES or MAIN_QRY_RES comes it allocates another machine which I confirmed was a different uuid. The Timeout of the previous machine fires anyway(with the 1st uuid).

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping root cause of this was in [gh321](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/321) for which I just pushed a fix. Would you mind try latest `1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` to see if it helps.